# Caching and persisting data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to do 2 things. I want to be able to cache data so that I can "save" variables when I move from 1 activity to another where the variables of the first are not needed in the second.

I also want to be able to formally save the data upon the file exiting.  Unfortunately my issue is, I can't find any documentation on how to complete these.

There are 4 strings (listed below) that I want to save long term as well as temporarily while moving within the activities.

`String[] name`
    `Double[] amount` 
  `Double[] rate` 
  `Integer[] term`  
Each String has room for 10 different pieces of data. The data will be sorted, and needs to be saved while I go to another activity which new data is input and carried to my first activity to be placed in these strings, and finally - saved.

Please provide suggestions or documentation links so I can learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question look a little confusing, but if you want to pass between `activity1` to `activity2` and preserve variable that you keep in `activity1`, you don't need to make nothing because androdi preserve that state, when you go back to `activity1` from `activity2`.Yoou can refer [`Saving variables state`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android) post for case y,ou want to save state in configuration changes. [`Passing activity data`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) to pass data between `activities` and for saving in file you have two options. [`Preferences`](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=1731) and [`Saving in File`](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=2035).

Comment: those are great links, thank you - I will be able to research what I want to do with all of those.

Comment: Also look into making the class a Parcelable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html  This will allow your instance to be passed from any context to another, via the "extras" bundle, in any intent.